# Is it possible to define a resolve object and make it available in all routes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a users with access to different parts of the app. What I'm doing now is adding a resolve to every $routeProvider.when

```
resolve : {
            adminUser: securityAuthorizationProvider.requireAuthenticatedUser,
            hasSiteAccess: securityAuthorizationProvider.requireSiteAccess,
            hasEmailAccess: securityAuthorizationProvider.requireEmailAccess
        }
```

And in every controller I'm adding "`hasSiteAccess`" and "`hasEmailAccess`", like this:

```
.controller('setup', ['$scope','hasSiteAccess','hasEmailAccess', function ($scope,  hasSiteAccess, hasEmailAccess) {
```

My app is broken into many modules and I want to make these available in all to display a friendly message.

Is it possible to make this resolve object available in all routes and controllers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the authorization provider before each route change via `$routeChangeStart` event:

```
.run(['$rootScope', 'securityAuthorization',
    function($rootScope, securityAuthorization) {

        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) {
            securityAuthorization.requireAuthenticatedUser();
            securityAuthorization.requireSiteAccess();
            securityAuthorization.requireEmailAccess();
        });
    }
])
```

Hope this helps